# No space left on Amazon Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker

I made sure to add 2 TB of storage space to my instance. I am trying to load this hugging face model

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.set_default_device("cuda")
else:
    torch.set_default_device("cpu")
    
model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/Orca-2-13b", device_map='auto')

# https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/27132
# please use the slow tokenizer since fast and slow tokenizer produces different tokens
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        "microsoft/Orca-2-13b",
        use_fast=False,
    )
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Here is a snapshot of my settings:

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1N0E.png]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the partition sizes.

Comment: @Marcin Where do I check the partition size?

Comment: Did you stop and start the instance post setting change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [SageMaker Studio Classic Launcher](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-launcher.html), in the "Notebooks and compute resources" section, launch a "System terminal", and check the disk usage with the command `df -h` (or `df -h .` to limit the output to the current disk). That will show you the size and usage of each partition.

You can also use Python:

```py
import shutil

# Get total, used and free disk space in GB
total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")

print(f"Total: {total // (2**30)} GiB")
print(f"Used: {used // (2**30)} GiB")
print(f"Free: {free // (2**30)} GiB")
```

If you discover that the partition where your Python environment and model are located is not large enough, you might need to resize the partition or change your setup to use the 2 TB storage you allocated.

---

> Following your code, I get this: `Total: 134 GiB Used: 86 GiB Free: 48 GiB` .
> How do I resize the partition or change the setup to use the 2TB storage I allocated?

Check first the AWS EC2 Management Console under the 'Volumes' section, to see if the 2TB volume is correctly attached to your SageMaker instance.

Comment: Following your code I get this

```
Total: 134 GiB
Used: 86 GiB
Free: 48 GiB
```
how do I resize the partition or change the setup to use the 2TB storage I allocated?

Comment: @Wolfy Not sure: check the AWS EC2 Management Console to confirm if you see your volume mounted.

Comment: There is nothing in the Volumes section of EC2 Management console...

Comment: @Wolfy I suspect that is the problem. I do not know where the volume of the notebook instance is supposed to show up.